# Application Crashed When Pressing Back Button on Android Camera Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

i have problem using camera in my Android application

i have a form for save data, there is a button to **Take Picture** with camera and the captured image from the camera will be placed on ImageView in my form.

there's no problem on calling camera intent and placing the image in the form

my problem is : 
in the camera application,
if i press back button (back to the form) my application **crashed**.

why?

this is the code on my button that call the camera

```
btn_takepic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {            
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
    }
});
```

this is my onActivityResult

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    final EditText et_foto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_foto);
    if(requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {          
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");  
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imv_foto);  
        image.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
        //toastkeun(data.getExtras().get("data").toString());
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

i'm testing on real device
this is my logCat

```
07-08 16:05:26.187: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12116): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-08 16:05:26.187: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12116): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.ngimagrid.nigmago/com.ngimagrid.nigmago.FormAsetTambah}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-08 16:05:26.187: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12116):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3515)
07-08 16:05:26.187: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12116):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3557)
07-08 16:05:26.187: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12116):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-08 16:05:26.187: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12116):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2063)
07-08 16:05:26.187: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12116):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-08 16:05:26.187: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12116):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-08 16:05:26.187: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12116):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-08 16:05:26.187: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12116):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 16:05:26.187: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12116):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-08 16:05:26.187: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12116):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
07-08 16:05:26.187: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12116):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
07-08 16:05:26.187: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12116):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-08 16:05:26.187: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12116): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-08 16:05:26.187: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12116):     at com.ngimagrid.nigmago.FormAsetTambah.onActivityResult(FormAsetTambah.java:246)
07-08 16:05:26.187: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12116):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3890)
07-08 16:05:26.187: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12116):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3511)
07-08 16:05:26.187: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12116):     ... 11 more
07-08 16:05:26.187: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12116): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-08 16:05:26.187: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12116): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.ngimagrid.nigmago/com.ngimagrid.nigmago.FormAsetTambah}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-08 16:05:26.187: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12116):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3515)
07-08 16:05:26.187: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12116):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3557)
07-08 16:05:26.187: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12116):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-08 16:05:26.187: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12116):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2063)
07-08 16:05:26.187: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12116):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-08 16:05:26.187: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12116):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-08 16:05:26.187: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12116):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-08 16:05:26.187: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12116):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 16:05:26.187: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12116):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-08 16:05:26.187: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12116):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
07-08 16:05:26.187: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12116):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
07-08 16:05:26.187: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12116):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-08 16:05:26.187: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12116): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-08 16:05:26.187: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12116):     at com.ngimagrid.nigmago.FormAsetTambah.onActivityResult(FormAsetTambah.java:246)
07-08 16:05:26.187: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12116):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3890)
07-08 16:05:26.187: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12116):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3511)
07-08 16:05:26.187: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12116):     ... 11 more
```

from this line, i think that's the problem...

```
07-08 16:05:26.187: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12116): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.ngimagrid.nigmago/com.ngimagrid.nigmago.FormAsetTambah}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

there's no result returned right?
how to fix that?

thanks

cmiiw

Comment: data.getExtras().get("data"); 

This line has some problems on various devices.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1480 

For some devices, the data is not returned with the bundle. I don't exactly remember which devices though. But, even if you get a Bitmap, that's of very low resolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is coming from your app. you can try to surround the whole onActivity result code in a try/catch block. i think what you are experiencing is a Camera bug on some of the phones. also try to try around different combinations of the extras you are sending on startActivityForResult intent.

Also always check the result code before you do anything. you dont want to make the same code if the result is canceled(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) or ok (Activity.RESULT_OK )

also there is a bug where the result doesn't come in the EXTRA_OUTPUT (i think it was named like that) but instead it comes as an Uri in intent.getData(). extra output is you providing a path where to save the file and the uri return is usually the image saved in the default camera location. its a bit different as you will see.

You are not using flags atm but you should if you want the image location as a result. Search stack for some sample code for the extras.

Comment: i surrounded my onActivityResult() with try/catch block, and it returned java.lang.NullPointerException when i press back button, so on catch block i left it blank, so the application wont crash.
Thanks :D

Comment: well read up a bit on handling exceptions if you aren't really familiar with them, but the right thing here is actually as i said to check the result code and if it is Activity.CANCELED than to skip the code you have for getting the image (with a simple case or if statement) so the exception isn't thrown in most of the cases.

Comment: try to surround the whole onActivity result code in a try/catch block. it's work ,Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 4):

The NullPointerException is caused by your code assuming that data.getExtras().get("data") will return something. This is an entirely undocumented parameter and on many (most) devices will return null.

If, as it appears, you're trying to get a thumbnail, you can try something like this, which tries both known (to me, anyway) ways in which to extract a thumbnail from the results of the Camera Intent.

```
Bitmap thumb;   
if (data.getData() != null) {
    try {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        thumb = Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getContentResolver(), Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment()), Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
        } catch (Exception typeNotSupported) {

        }
    }
    if (thumb == null) {
        thumb = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    }
}
```

Incidentally I think there's another bug - your onActivityResult should also test that resultCode is OK - if the user cancels from the Camera I believe onActivityResult will still be called.

I hope that's useful.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can handle back button while on gallery or camera or any other by this way.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) 
    {
    //Here you can handle,do anything you want
    }
//other code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be solved with a simple trick

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)   {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode==0)
    {
        return;
    }
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question

Comment: I had the same problem that the app crashes after pressing the back button.The task was to get an image from the user via camera or gallery and place it in an activity. I have searched everywhere for a solution and did'nt get an easy one at last I came up with this solution and it worked for me I have given the remaining statements in else if statement like getting the image from camera and gallery.Sorry to know that it did'nt work for you but it worked perfectly fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Your talking about the youtube video I know, I had the same error.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try 
    {    
            Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.takePhoto);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                       Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                       startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                }

             });
            iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    } 
     catch (Exception e) 
    {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```